# How to reorganize HTML file content by command in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I have many many SVG files that are generated by Adobe Illustrator.
I need to edit repeat content inside these SVG files. For detail, I need to move `id="size1"` from `<g>` to the end of `<text>`

#### For example:

From:

```
<g id="size1">
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 813.6582 187.3535)"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st0 st1 st2">Small</tspan></text>
</g>
```

To:

```
<g>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 813.6582 187.3535)" id="size1"><tspan x="0" y="0" class="st0 st1 st2">Small</tspan></text>
</g>
```

There are many lines like that and many files with same content. I wasted to much time to edit them manually, is there any way that I can write a Linux script.sh file to run to help me do it faster? Please advise.

Thank for all replies.

Comment: Why did you use a tag whose description starts with "Don't use this tag"?

Comment: You can do this using `awk`. When it processes a `<g>` line, it saves the id in a variable. When it processes the next `<text>` line, it inserts the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --inplace --delete "//g/@id" --insert "//g/text" --type attr -n id -v "size1" yourfile.svg
```

where:

```
  --omit-decl - omit xml declaration <?xml version="1.0"?>      
  --inplace   - to actually change file specified as last argument 
  --delete (+arguments) - delete id node under <g>
  --insert (+arguments) - insert id="size1" in <text> under <g>
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants to move the *value* of the id attribute, not the actual text `size1`.

Comment: Right, then my answer is not much valuable... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT to transform the SVG file's XML to your desired format:

```sh
$ xsltproc <(cat <<'EOF'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="//g">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name() = 'id')]|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//g/text">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF
) foo.xml > fixed_foo.xml
```

---

This assumes you're using a shell like `bash` or `zsh` that supports `<()` style command redirection. Otherwise put the stylesheet in its own file